# How to dump "sourced mel script" from autodesk maya memory?

Tags: reverse-engineering, dump, maya, mel

Maya is a 3d animatin package, and it has a scripting lanaguage named MEL which looks very similar to C syntax. My question is sometimes people encrypted their mel code, wrap them inside a .mll plugin. and source the code into memory before calling it. is there a way to dump the source code of the "sourced" interactively code ?

eg

```
global proc helloWorld(){

    print "Yeah hello world!";

}
```

if i paste these lines into maya script editor, and ctrl-entered("sourced") it.   with only knowing the proc name  helloWorld, is it possible to "dump" the original source code from memory ( asumming it's not encrypted in memory, which i think most probably it isn't because of speed considerations)?

or what tools do i need to do this or which directions should i be considering ? thanks !

edit: maybe use winappdbg to dump the process' memory and search for the proc name string? Found this code snippet 
[Dump the memory of a process](http://winappdbg.sourceforge.net/MoreExamples.html#dump-the-memory-of-a-process)

Comment: no, but if its truly mel then you can read the string in the debugger. Possibly also in the dll file itself. But there is no guarantee it ais mel at all. A alternative way would be to reconstruct the mel enviroment. usually tough its easier to replicate what it does.

Comment: To add a bit even if its encrypted in memory it still needs to be passed to maya unencrypted.  but that encryption has a neglible impact on speed. Anyway i have done this to test protectors, but it would be illegal for you to do this in many jurisdictions without permission from  the author.

Comment: Frankly, why do you want to do this? Is there a problem you're hoping to solve?

Comment: @mhlester he wants to circumvent copy protection.

Comment: Ah, thanks @joojaa. I was looking at it backwards, as if he was trying to remove his code from memory. Didn't click he's trying to read someone else's